# Como evitar el for en R para recorrer las variables de un dataframe

Tags: r

En un dataframe quiero añadir una nueva variable y los valores calcularlos aplicando una función a la que le paso como parametro el valor de una de las variables ya existentes

Es decir, parto de este dataframe
[image: df de base]

y yo solo soy capaz de hacerlo asi

```
contratado<-function(proyectoID){
sql<-paste0("SELECT  SUM(Detalle.LineTotal) AS Importe
FROM    FULCRUM.dbo.RDR1 AS Detalle INNER JOIN
    FULCRUM.dbo.ORDR AS Cabecera ON Detalle.DocEntry = Cabecera.DocEntry INNER JOIN
    FULCRUM.dbo.OPRJ AS Proyectos ON Detalle.Project = Proyectos.PrjCode
WHERE Cabecera.DocStatus = \'o\' AND Detalle.Project=",dbQuoteString(con,proyectoID))
return (dbGetQuery(con,sql))
}

SumaContratado<-function(df){
for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-contratado(df$ProyectoID[indiceFila])
}
return(df)
```

}

```
df<-df%>%
mutate(Contratado=0)

df <- SumaContratado(df)
```

Pero asumo que usando spply o map se deberia poder evitar ese bucle for fila por fila pero no soy capaz de enconrar la manera de hacerlo funcionar

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

En su forma más sencilla, dado un vector X, sapply(X, funcion) aplica la función a cada elemento de X. En tu ciclo `for`, estarías sobreescribiendo cada elemento del dataframe df en la columna ncol(df). 
Si contratado() es la función y df$ProyectoID es la columna, entonces la instrucción sería:

`df[,ncol(df)] <- sapply(df$ProyectoID, contratado)`

Por las dudas podrías probar que hace `sapply(df$ProyectoID, contratado)` sola, para ver si da el vector esperado

Un ejemplo, totalmente artificial sería

```
> # creo un df con dos columnas y 5 filas, lleno con letras
> df <- data.frame(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5])
> names(df) <- c("proyectoID", "Descrip")
> df
  proyectoID Descrip
1          a       A
2          b       B
3          c       C
4          d       D
5          e       E
> # creo una función que dado un ID (una letra), me devuelve un número
> # (su posición en este caso)
> contratado <- function(proyectoID) {
+   # de esta manera solo me devuelve uno y solo un número
+   # no se puede aplicar a un vector proyectoID
+   # la verdadera contratado() no admite vectores porque
+   # dbGetQuery(con,sql) admite una sola consulta sql
+   match(proyectoID, letters[1:5])[1]
+ }
> 
> # por ejemplo devuelve 4
> contratado("d")
[1] 4
> 
> # agrego al df el resultado
> df[,ncol(df)+1] <- sapply(df$proyectoID, contratado)
> df
  proyectoID Descrip V3
1          a       A  1
2          b       B  2
3          c       C  3
4          d       D  4
5          e       E  5
```

Comment: contratado es una función que hace una consulta en base de datos y obtiene una único valor numérico con el importe contratado de cada proyecto y cuando intento la primera propuesta que me comentas me sale este error
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , ncol(df) + 1, value = list(ANACA040.Importe = NA_real_,  :
  provided 109 variables to replace 1 variables y si intento la segunda este otro df[,ncol(df)+1] <- contratado(df$ProyectoID)
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=109].

Comment: Claro, ahi vi la función contratado, el paste0 te debe generar un vector con todas las consultas pero dbGetQuery recibe solo una consulta por vez, en un vector de longitud uno, así que la segunda forma directa sin sapply no va a funcionar.

Comment: Sería bueno ver un ejemplo de como es el df. Voy a editar la respuesta, pero `df[,ncol(df)+1] <- contratado(df$ProyectoID)` debería aplicar `contratado()` a cada elemento de df$ProyectoID, que es similar al ciclo for.